# Numbers vs string/expressions vs values

Tags: ruby

When I type the following:

```
print "2+2 is equal to" +2+2
```

I get an error message saying I can't convert a number into a string, but when I type:

```
print "2+2 is equal to", 2+2
```

it's accepting it and displays:

```
2+2 is equal to4
```

What's the difference between the two? It's not making logical sense to me. Could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 3):

```
print "2+2 is equal to" + 2 + 2
```

Here you're trying to add a number to a string. This operation doesn't make sense. It's like adding an apple to a cat. The addition fails, but if it were to succeed, then `print` would print the result.

```
print "2+2 is equal to", 2 + 2
```

Here you're telling the `print` command to print this string and also result of summing these two numbers. it knows how to print strings and how to print numbers. Strings and numbers don't have to be mixed together in this case, they are handled separately. That's why this operation succeeds.

You can make the first operation work too. For this, you must be explicit that you want this number as a string, so that both addition operands are strings and can be actually added together.

```
print "2+2 is equal to" + (2 + 2).to_s
```

or

```
print "2+2 is equal to #{2 + 2}" # this is called string interpolation
```

Some languages try to be friendly and, if you're adding a number to a string, will stringify the number for you. Results can be... surprising.

Javascript:

```
"2 + 2 equals to " + 2 + 2 
# => "2 + 2 equals to 22"

"2 + 2 equals to " + (2 + 2) 
# => "2 + 2 equals to 4"
```

It's good that ruby doesn't do this kind of tricks :)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thanks. I'll have nightmares tonight :)

Comment: I suggest that you elaborate, "This operation doesn't make sense." by explaining the technical reason for the exception: the method [String#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) requires its argument (here `4`) to be a string. –  Cary Swoveland just now   edit

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Not sure I agree. `String#+` requiring its argument to be a String is the concequence of the lack of sense here, not the cause.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: oh, and BTW, the argument is `2`, not `4` :)

Comment: Ah, yes, `2`. I had to patch `String#+` to confirm that's true. :-) Sometimes I get tripped up on the most basic things. We'll see if I can remember, "left-to-right, left-to-right..". Oh, and I did use the word, "elaborate".

Answer (score 1):

Everybody's pointed out how `print` works, so i thought i'd shed a bit of light on `+`.

These two operators look the same, right?

1. `'2'+'2'`
2. `2+2`

In actual fact, there are two very different operations happening:

1. [String#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) - This concatenates the argument to the source string. Argument must be a string.
2. [Fixnum#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2B) - This adds the argument to the source number. Argument must be a number.

So if String#+ only works on `string` objects, how is it that we can print different types of objects?

Some classes are very 'string-like' and can be treated as strings in most contexts (eg. `Exception` before Ruby 1.9) as they implement `to_str`(implicit conversion).

We can also implement `to_s` in our own objects to allow it to return a `String` representation of the object (explicit conversion).

You can read more about this at http://codeloveandboards.com/blog/2014/03/18/explicit-vs-implicit-conversion-methods/

Answer (score 0):

```
print "2+2 is equal to" +2+2
```

is equivalent to:

```
print("2+2 is equal to" +2+2)
```

You are trying to add an integer `2` to a string `"2+2 is equal to"`.

---

```
print "2+2 is equal to", 2+2
```

is equivalent to:

```
print("2+2 is equal to", 2+2)
```

Here `print` takes two arguemnts, one is a string, the other is an expression `2+2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "2+2 is equal to" + 2+2
```

fails because it tries to add a integer to a string before the result is send to `print`. An operation that does not make sense. Whereas:

```
print "2+2 is equal to", 2+2
```

is a other operation. Here you send two argument to `print`. A string and an integer. Internally `print` calls `to_s` on both values.

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-print):

> `print(obj, ...)` → `nil`
>
> Prints each object in turn to `$stdout`. [...] Objects that aren't strings will be converted by calling their `to_s` method.

Another way to do this is string interpolation, that also calls `to_s` automatically:

```
print "2+2 is equal to #{2+2}"
```